# How to hide canvas content from parent rounded corners in any webkit for Mac?

Tags: canvas, css

I have a parent `div` with rounded corners that contains a `canvas`:

```
<div id="box">
    <canvas width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
</div>​

#box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```

The canvas renders a red rectangle that overflows the parent. As expected, this is what I get in all browsers:

[image]

### The problem:

However, for webkit browsers running in Mac OS lion (I tested Safari 5.1.5 and Chrome 19), the canvas is still visible in the round corners:

[image]

Interestingly, this problem seems to happen only when the inner element is a `canvas`. For any other child element, the content is correctly hidden.

One workaround would be to apply the same rounded corners to the canvas itself, but unfortunately this is not possible, since I need to animate the canvas relative position.

Another workaround that should work, is to redraw the canvas in a clipped region that resembles the rounded corners shape, but I would prefer a cleaner CSS3 solution.

**So, does one know how to fix this for Safari and Chrome on Mac?**

**EDIT**: Problem also happens in Chrome on Win7

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/PJqXY/8/)

Comment: No specific answer (although I tried a few bits and pieces) but it looks like a manifestation of https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68196

Comment: Confirmed that the same bug exists on Chrome on the Mac

Comment: @NathanD.Ryan Thanks for pointing that out. I have changed the question to include also Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bug still exists (11/2015), but another workaround is to add `position: relative;` to the `overflow:hidden;` element.

Comment: Thanks! Seems `position relative` now works for the latest builds. I remember doing that back in 2012 without success.

Comment: I had to also give it a z-index, but yeah this worked for me.

Comment: This saved the day also in year 2019.

Answer (score 10):

[Issue 137818:  Large canvas does not honor containing div's border-radius](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=137818)

I solved this with CSS tag to parent div to:

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

it works on the current chrome version 36.0.1985.143 m

[jsfiddle.net/PJqXY/38](http://jsfiddle.net/PJqXY/38)/

```
#box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: For me, this does not work on Safari 8.  I had to use -webkit-mask answer below.

Comment: Worked for me on Safari 12. Thank you, @Dowai!

Answer (score 6):

Here's the code to add in the css :

```
 -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); /* this fixes the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
```

**HTML Source Code**

```
<div id="box">
  <canvas width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Css Source Code**

```
#box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); /* this fixes the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
}
```

**Javascript Source Code**

```
var $canvas = $("canvas");

if ($canvas[0].getContext) {
    var context = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
    context.fillRect(10, 10, 300, 60);
}
```

**Note : This Need's Jquery**

Example :
http://jsfiddle.net/PJqXY/12/

Comment: I've tried this solution before, but unfortunately it does not work for Safari 5.1.7 Win7. The disadvantage of using masks is the dependency with the border-radius. If I change the border-radius, will need a new mask image. Anyway, I gave you +1 for your effort and for making a base64 coded image that saves an extra HTTP request.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I found out:

In the canvas element, when the multiplication of `width` by `height` is 66000 or greater, the canvas ignores the parent's overflow property.

For example, the following one fails, because 300*220 = 66000

```
<canvas width="300" height="220"></canvas>
```

This one works fine:

```
<canvas width="300" height="219"></canvas>
```

I've found this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129732) after googling for "canvas 66000". It is not related with overflow, but I am sure is the same bug.

**Thanks for Jeemusu for pointing me in the right direction.**

Comment: Try using a canvas of size 256x256 (success), then try 256x257 (failure), that means that the limit is suspiciously close to 65,536 or 2^16 pixels.

Comment: @lazd You are right. To be more precise, this problem happens when the width*height > 2^16

Comment: Well, what I said before is not totally correct (width*height > 2^16), but that the limit is suspiciously close 2^16

Answer (score 3):

Does the canvas have to use a width/height value? If you set the height of the canvas in the html to a smaller value, or even remove the values all together it gets clipped properly (only tested in Chrome).

http://jsfiddle.net/LwZ6v/

Comment: +1 That's a great workaround that fixes the issue in Chrome and Safari! Thanks a lot!! However, it's not clear why works for `height` <= 219px, but fails for values >= 220px (assuming `width` remains unchanged to 300px)

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to me either. If it worked for `height <= 140px`, which is the height - 10px margin of the red canvas, I could understand... but where it gets 219px from I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

I found an asfwer for Safari. Add webkit mask with single pixel png to the parent and the clipping of overflowing parts will render fine.

```
-webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
```

[JsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/LwZ6v/222/)