# CSS overflow:hidden inside circles

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide the overflow of a circular div. Its child div is hidden from view when outside the container area (good), but remains visible when only outside the radius area (bad)

```
.outer{
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 50%;               
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background:#dedede;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner{
    position: absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:150px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    background:#98de45;
}​
```

Overall I'd like to achieve the effect at http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0 but using circles - is there a way to do this?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/a9Feu/

Edit: This works fine in Firefox and IE 10, but not Chrome or Safari

Comment: It works fine in IE 10 - update your question with details of the browser you are using

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616668/how-to-hide-canvas-content-from-parent-rounded-corners-in-any-webkit-for-mac

Comment: yes! it looks like the same problem... any workaround?

Comment: @user1284316: I think it's classified as a bug. So, there's probably not a straightforward workaround. I don't know of one, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
.outer{
    position:static;
    border-radius: 50%;               
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background:#dedede;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner{
    position: static;
    top:150px;
    left:150px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    background:#98de45;
}​
```

Comment: Interesting that the positioning is what causes it to not work. If I were you, however, I would edit your solution to change the `top` and `left` properties in `.inner` to be `margin-top` and `margin-left` so that the square gets positioned correctly. Whether going to a static element is an option for the OP is a whole other issue.

Comment: Then you should use HTML canvas instead of css. I've found something about it, give me some time to find it again.

Comment: continuing ScottS though... what if I need to use absolute position?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work

http://jsfiddle.net/a9Feu/35/

```
.inner{
    position: absolute;
    **border-bottom-right-radius: 100% 110%;**
    top:150px;
    left:150px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: red;
    background:#98de45;
}​
```