# Border radius, Z-index, overflow breaking

Tags: overflow, z-index, css, css-position

I have two divs with `border-radius` set to max to make them circles. I have a header div in the first circle with a different `background-color` and `overflow:hidden` so that it looks like the top portion of the circle is a different color.

The second circle I want to be underneath the first, basically peaking out. The problem is, as soon as I set `position:relative` (or anything else), the overflow on the header background color for Chrome and Safari.

This should be doable. Help? Thoughts?

- [Red should be behind green](http://live.bluefantail.com/demo.html).
- [Header should be partially hidden by overflow](http://live.bluefantail.com/demo-2.html).

Comment: How about placing another DIV round the large circle and setting the position:relative and z-index on that?

Comment: The demos look the same to me.

Comment: @roelandvanbeek sorry, forgot to update it. Updated!

Comment: @BillyMoat Success! Thanks! For some reason, I always forget about throwing extra wrappers on things.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616668/how-to-hide-canvas-content-from-parent-rounded-corners-in-any-webkit-for-mac.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer for you to accept if that's cool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try placing another DIV round the large circle and setting the position:relative and z-index on that.

Comment: Success! Thanks a lot! If anyone else is doing this, make sure both the container element and the overlapped element are set with a position, or z-index doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is kinda' what you're looking for.

http://codepen.io/AntonNiklasson/pen/kxwFB

Or am I missing something?