# HTML5 Canvas with rounded corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, rounded-corners

I'd like to have an HTML5 canvas with rounded corner. I'm using the CSS property `border-radius: 15px` to round my corners.

But, when I draw something in the corner of my canvas, I can draw in the corner.

At the beginning:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Do you have any solution to avoid that? I thought about create a mask but I don't really know how to do..
For information, this works on Firefox but not on Chrome/Safari/Opera.

This is a small example:

http://jsfiddle.net/XYHpJ/

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you can draw in the corner if you choose? or when you draw in the corner it stops being round how you want? Any chance of an example?

Comment: Your Fiddle is PERFECTLY working on Firefox. The **What I want** part is achieved, while the **What I have** part does not occur. What on earth ?...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use this example on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12336233/1312570

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rzSmw/

```
#canvas_container
{
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height: 515px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 690px;

    /* this fixes the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
}
```

Comment: This definitely hides the corners, but the line that is drawn in the fiddle still exists outside the rounded corners, you just can't see it.

Comment: Fantastic answer! I was floating a div over a canvas element and couldn't for the life of me figure out why my `border-radius` wasn't working with `overflow:hidden` until I hide the canvas and it worked. Any explanation for why this works? I initially assumed the image was a fixed radius but it seems to be working for any value of border-radius for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's due to a bug in webkit. I can see that the initial code works now in the latest Chrome on Windows. But basically the fix is that by adding a transparent 1x1 png as a mask it will then make it work as intended.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to avoid that is by inserting the `<canvas>` inside a "container" tag and then apply the `border-radius` to the container. Like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container > div {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

A working example: http://jsbin.com/onuqid/2/

You can also use `display: block;` and get rid of the wrapper as [Allendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007903/html5-canvas-with-rounded-corner#comment21083821_15008092) suggested in the comments.

Comment: Try adding `-moz-border-radius: 10px;` and `-webkit-border-radius: 10px;`. And for IE use this meta-tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

Comment: @tilix Check my edit. Sorry, I forgot to add the `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @NathanCampos You can just change the canvas object to `display: block;` and it will just accept work fine, no wrapper needed per-se :)

Comment: Your example is a div inside a div. I'm working with canvas. Please check out my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/XYHpJ/ and try to draw in the corner.