# How can i make video border curve?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I wanna make video style just like this... (curve)

I tried to search & think how to performance this but i couldn't find it?

Is there anyone who can help me?

Thank you..

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: This has already been answered on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007903/html5-canvas-with-rounded-corner/15090794

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Chrome and Safari do not support border-radius on  elements. But If you create a div container with rounded corners and overflow hidden, and then place the video in it. it will be right.

```
<style>
.video-div{
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
</style>


<div class="video-div">
    <video></video>
</div>
```