# Cannot figure out how to get css/js masking code to work in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, image-masking

I have found [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616668/how-to-hide-canvas-content-from-parent-rounded-corners-in-any-webkit-for-mac/12336233#12336233) and I thought sweet I just have to plug it in, but I am new to Meteor and I am hopefully just making simple naive mistakes. I thought that jquery was already included in Meteor and that if I use $ or document.getElementById in the "Client" code section that it would work, but I either get a null for the latter and a $ is not defined for the former :(

I tried to be as concise as possible with my code in this post.

Here is the javascript code for the masking in my project:

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");;
  if (canvas[0].getContext) {
      var context = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fillRect(10, 10, 300, 60);
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant css code:

```
#box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAA5JREFUeNpiYGBgAAgwAAAEAAGbA+oJAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); /* this fixes the overflow:hidden in Chrome/Opera */
}
```

html code:

```
<template name="applicationLayout">
<div id = "backgroundDiv">
</div>

<div id="box">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="width: 40%">
  <header>
      {{> logoFloat}}
      {{> navbar}}
  </header>
  {{> yield}}
  {{> footer}}
</div>
```

**UPDATE** I was able to get this to work by using Salman's Template.applicationLayout.onRendered() function and then anomepani javascript dom selector code and by adding id="canvas" to my canvas object. Thank you guys for your help, I wish I could mark both as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap up your client code in **onRendered** method

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.applicationLayout.onRendered(function(){
        var $canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        if (canvas[0].getContext) {
            var context = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
            context.fillStyle = 'red';
            context.fillRect(10, 10, 300, 60);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have copied code from [Example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616668/how-to-hide-canvas-content-from-parent-rounded-corners-in-any-webkit-for-mac/12336233#12336233) but you have mixed up jQuery selector and javascript DOM selector that's why it  is not working

Try this one using javascript dom selector

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");;
  if (canvas.getContext) {
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fillRect(10, 10, 300, 60);
  }
```

or Try this one using jQuery selector

```
      var $canvas = $("#canvas");
        //you can create variable canvas instead '$canvas' both works
      if ($canvas[0].getContext) {
          var context = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
          context.fillStyle = 'red';
          context.fillRect(10, 10, 300, 60);
      }
```

Comment: For some reason I still get "$" is not a function even if I wrap it up in if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.applicationLayout.onRendered(function(){}});

Comment: @smuggledpancakes Can you please share some code in jsfiddle so I can track down. '$' is not function means $ sign is defined and jquery loaded otherwise it throws reference error

Comment: I think the $ is not a function because I have to use it inside of onCreated, onRendered, or onDestroyed function, see here http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_inst. I am pretty sure this is it.