# Overflow not working for (pixi) canvas positioned outside it's parent (offscreen)

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, html5-canvas, pixi.js

On flowen.me, I'm using the PIXI canvas to generate an effect (it's my photo with a scroll effect).

I have tried different elements with overflow: body, div child of body containing all other elements, parent element itself, etc. But the horizontal scroll bar always appears. Whether I use overflow-x or just overflow.

I tested this on my Chrome browser, iPhone SE, latest IOS and on my MacBook Pro. All sharing the same results.

Anyone have a suggestion or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didn't search correctly before I posted, this gave me the answer:
[How to hide canvas content from parent rounded corners in any webkit for Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616668/how-to-hide-canvas-content-from-parent-rounded-corners-in-any-webkit-for-mac)

a position:relative to the element with overflow hidden