# HTML5 Canvas - Hide text parts when it's out of my rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My problem is simple. I just want to make invisible text parts when it's out of my rectangle. This image will help to understand what I want. How can I make invisible gray parts of text at canvas? Thanks for help! [image]

Comment: This might be applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616668/how-to-hide-canvas-content-from-parent-rounded-corners-in-any-webkit-for-mac

Comment: Yes but I don't want solve it with css because my project is on canvas completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After drawing your rectangle, invoke

```
ctx.clip();
```

Then draw the parts that should be only inside it.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop"`

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 400;
let ch = canvas.height = 110;
ctx.fillStyle = "#ccc";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(100,25,200,60);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-atop"
ctx.font="2em Verdana";
ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";

ctx.fillText("This is some text",110,65);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but ctx.clip(); is the simplest way I think :)